# AWS Elastic Beanstalks shows "whoops! there was an error" on its url after uploading Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need your help. I have created a website on Laravel and its working totally fine on my localhost but when I deploy it on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk it shows "Whoops There was an error" title page only without any error or text on the page except title.

I have tried many options like changing env file name, generating app key, changing root folder from / to /public but it just doesn't work. Below I am sharing you my folder structure that I am uploading to AWS beanstalk after zipping. Here is elastic beanstalk url.  http://lessyes.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

[image]

Comment: Can you see log files?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze thanks for the comment. Can you please specify where I can see the logs in aws?

Comment: Just found logs on elastic bean stalk. Here is the images of log folder content. It has many files which one should I analyse? https://imgur.com/a/ORH3YNQ

Comment: go to httpd and see error.log

Comment: Here please https://imgur.com/a/2mExuIr

Comment: nothing important here. can you look at laravel.log and also your nginx configuration to see your config log?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze dont you think this is due to the below error?
The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.




By laravel.log you mean .env file? can you please specify.

Comment: I don't think that above error could cause error. laravel log file is in your root folder/storage/logs

Comment: for this I think I have to SSH in to my elastic beanstalk instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207123/discussion-between-malkhazi-dartsmelidze-and-faisal-shani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your file/folder permissions

[How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

> sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
>   sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

For your `cache` directory:

> sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

Answer (score 3):

This is for future users - if you are not seeing actual errors other than  "Whoops There was an error", this probably means your app is not in debug mode. To see errors stack, you may want to enable debug temporarily:
Make sure APP_DEBUG is set to TRUE (`APP_DEBUG=TRUE`) in your app's .env file.

Note: Making the above-mentioned change means anyone with read access to your app can see those errors and perhaps get to know more than he/she should about your business logic/data.

Comment: Hey @qumber  thanks for the reply. But when I zipped and uploaded my folder on AWS APP-DEBUg was set to true but it didnt show the error only showed the page with just title "Whoops There was an error".

Comment: @FaisalShani You might also want to check for the same in config/app.php (Not required in and above Laravel 5). 
Also, check if in your server's php.ini, you have `display_errors=On` (http://php.net/display-errors).
And, did you run `composer update/install` on the server?

Lastly, here is a gist I made to log exceptions to CloudWatch using Monolog (Ensure that `APP_ENV` is NOT set to `local` for this to work):
https://gist.github.com/qumberrizvi/f43933521a3d1aec11d4bf10d49675b2